# How to run crobjob to create directory on desktop

Tags: cron

I tried command like
* * * * * mkdir new /home/subir/Desktop
But it create  "new" directory in my home directory.
How to do that On desktop?

Comment: Try `mkdir /home/subdir/Desktop/new` But why do you want this in a cronjob? As it stands it's something you only want to do once.

Comment: Just out of curiosity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of `mkdir` is simple. From `man mkdir` :

```
   mkdir [OPTION]... DIRECTORY...
```

Thus the correct use is `mkdir /home/subir/Desktop/new`, *not* `mkdir directory /path`.

When you specify multiple arguments, and none of them are options, `mkdir` will threat them as seperate directories to make. Thus, it tried to make `new` *and* `/home/subir/Desktop`.

You should probably learn [to use man pages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/795206/how-to-effectively-use-the-man-pages) to figure out such things quickly yourself.